# Easygui калькулятор

Tags: python

При выборе суммы или вычитания программа все равно перемножает числа. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```
from easygui import *

n1 = integerbox("Enter first number 1-10:", lowerbound = 1, upperbound = 10)

n2 = integerbox("Enter second number 1-10:", lowerbound = 1, upperbound = 10)

sum = n1 + n2

substraction = n1-n2

multiplication = n1 * n2

ch = ["+", "-", "*"]

action = buttonbox("Choose:", choices = ch)

if ch == "+":

   msgbox("The result is " + str(sum) + ".")

elif ch == "-":

   msgbox ("The result is " + str(substraction) + ".")

else:

   msgbox("The result is " + str(multiplication) + ".")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же сохраняете нажатую кнопку в переменную `action`, но при этом сравниваете со списком `ch`, естественно у вас и выполняется код из `else`. Сделайте чтобы в `if`'ах у вас сравнение было с переменной `action`:

```
action = buttonbox("Choose:", choices = ch)
if action == "+":
   msgbox("The result is " + str(sum) + ".")
elif action == "-":
   msgbox ("The result is " + str(substraction) + ".")
else:
   msgbox("The result is " + str(multiplication) + ".")
```